# How to get new session value after some time using PHP

Tags: php, session

I need to get the new session value after some second using PHP. My code is below.

```
<button class="btn nextbtnbgdiv open2" type="button">Next <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
<div class="fyndspacecategory fyndsheightsubc nano">
<div class="nano-content">
<?php
$cat_id= $_SESSION['cid'];
?>
</div>
</div>
```

Here when user is clicking on `next` button the div section is opening and the the value is fetching from session. Here i need after some second always the updated  `$_SESSION['cid']` will fetch at each time click on `next` button.

Comment: Sounds like you should be looking up Ajax

Comment: What is the purpose of the `next` button? Does it navigate the page, call content via Ajax, display an existing `div`? When and where does `$_SESSION['cid']` update in order to fetch a new value?

Comment: @WilliamIsted : `$_SESSION['cid']` has already updated before here i need to always display the updated value.

Comment: It sounds to me like when you click `next` you want an `ajax` or `XMLHttpRequest` to fetch that value from your website.

Comment: @WilliamIsted : Let me to explain again. When user will click on `next` button the `<div class="fyndspacecategory fyndsheightsubc nano">` is displaying to user. In this place i need to fetch the  `$_SESSION['cid']` after one second.thats it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139134/discussion-between-william-isted-and-satya).

Answer (score 0):

In order to fetch the updated `$_SESSION['cid']` you will need to make a call to the server to return this value, you can do so by embedding the value into an element i.e.

Back-end (i.e. get_session.php):

```
<html>
<body>
    <div id="session"><?= $_SESSION['cid'] ?></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Front-end:

```
<button class="btn nextbtnbgdiv open2" type="button">Next <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
<div class="fyndspacecategory fyndsheightsubc nano">
    <div class="nano-content"><?php $cat_id= $_SESSION['cid']; ?></div>
</div>

<script>
jQuery(function($) {

    $(document).on( 'click', '.nextbtnbgdiv', function() {
        $('.fyndspacecategory .nano-content').load('/get_session.php', '#session');
    });

});
</script>
```

Or you could use a header within a page to access `$_SESSION['cid']`.

```
<?php
if ( isset( $_GET['get_session'] ) && $_GET['get_session'] ) {
    header( 'X-Session: ' . $_SESSION['cid'] );
    exit;
}
?>

<button class="btn nextbtnbgdiv open2" onclick="javascript:getSession();" type="button">Next <span class="fa fa-arrow-right"></span></button>
<div class="fyndspacecategory fyndsheightsubc nano">
    <div class="nano-content" id="sessionId"><?php $cat_id= $_SESSION['cid']; ?></div>
</div>

<script>
function getSession() {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.onerror = function() { console.warn('An error occurred while checking session.'); };
request.open('HEAD', '?get_session=true', true);
    request.onload = function() {
        if ( request.getResponseHeader('X-Session') ) {
            document.getElementById("sessionId").innerHTML = request.getResponseHeader('X-Session');
        }
    };
    request.send();
}
</script>
```

This is not tested but should be enough to give you a start to complete your goal.